# Correct way to create Ubuntu Scope Project?

Tags: ubuntu-sdk, scopes, 15.04

Recently I tried to write an ubuntu scope project using ubuntu-sdk in 15.04, I found that no matter what I set the name, nickname and scope name, the appid (or package) will have the name at the beginning, which is something like:

name: **ScopeProject**

nickname: **scope1**

scopeName: **myscope**

appid generated: **scopeproject.scope1_myscope**

How can I set the appid be something like **"my_namespace_in_ubuntu_ developer.scopeproject"** using the project wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *appid* is not the package name. What you need to have set as you are asking, is the package name, and it should be set that way in the *manifest.json* file already. If it is not, it is a bug and you should report it in Launchpad.